# Macro to cut and paste row based on cell contents is only half working - cutting cells but they are not pasting

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro running that is used to cut and paste the contents of a row on the sheet Open Actions when column L contains either the statement Complete or the statement Held.

Both of these two statements determine which sheet the row is supposed to be cut and pasted into.

- If the contents of row L is Complete then move to Completed Actions
- If the contents of row L is Held then move to Held Actions

The contents of the table do not start until row 6 as there are titles and headings above, the same for the destination tables.

I cannot seem to be able to specify the specific row the cut and pasted cells are to populate on to.

This is a copy of the code I have so far:

I have tried multiple VBA methods and cannot seem to locate the one that works.

```
Sub completeaction()

Set wsOne = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Open Actions")
Set wsTwo = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Completed Actions")
Set ws.Three = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Held Actions")

lastRow = wsOne.Cells(wsOne.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

MsgBox lastRow

For i = 1 To lastRow
    lastOutRow = wsTwo.Cells(wsTwo.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If wsOne.Range("L" & i).Value = "Complete" Or wsOne.Range("L" & i).Value = "Held" Then
            wsTwo.Rows(lastOutRow).Value = wsOne.Rows(i).Value
            wsOne.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
Next

End Sub
```

The desired outcome for this macro is that the rows will move to the respective worksheets depending on what has been stated in Row L

Answer (score 1):

A few things.

- I think you need to split your If as the two different conditions
  need to result in different outcomes; hence you also need a variable to
  find the last row in each of the two sheets
- Get into the habit of declaring your variables (use Option Explicit)
- As you are deleting rows too, loop backwards to avoid skipping rows

  ```
  Sub completeaction()

  Dim wsOne As Worksheet 'etc
  Dim lastRowOne As Long 'etc

  Set wsOne = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Open Actions")
  Set wsTwo = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Completed Actions")
  Set wsThree = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Held Actions")

  lastRowOne = wsOne.Cells(wsOne.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  lastrowtwo = wsTwo.Cells(wsTwo.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  lastrowthree = wsThree.Cells(wsThree.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

  For i = lastRowOne To 1 Step -1
      If wsOne.Range("L" & i).Value = "Complete" Then
          wsTwo.Rows(lastrowtwo).Value = wsOne.Rows(i).Value
          wsOne.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
          lastrowtwo = lastrowtwo + 1
       ElseIf wsOne.Range("L" & i).Value = "Held" Then
          wsThree.Rows(lastrowthree).Value = wsOne.Rows(i).Value
          wsOne.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
          lastrowthree = lastrowthree + 1
      End If
  Next

  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Hi SJR thanks for coming back with a solution, I have copied in the above code and tried to run the macro but for some reason nothing is happening to the rows that contain values in column L. Is there something I am missing with your provided code?

Comment: Have you stepped through using F8 to see what's going on? Try it with a sample of one row and manually enter "Complete" or "Held" in column L and try that.

Comment: I have tried with just the first row having a complete status and ran through to it with F8. This may be a super basic question but I should have this code on sheet1 and not as a module, correct? Appreciate you helping me out here! :)

Comment: And what happened? Put it in a standard module, but being in a sheet module shouldn’t stop it working.

Comment: I applied it as a stand alone module and ran it but nothing happened, there were no errors returned, it just didnt run the action, Ill try it again and see if I get anymore luck, thanks! :).

Comment: That suggests the conditions weren’t met.

Comment: Sorry to dig this one back from graveyard, but this helped me a lot, but I have one issue. Since this loops from bottom to top, the copied data at bottom is reversed. Is there any way to sort the copied data in the way they appear in original table (top to bottom)?